# When was System.Hash introduced in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Newer versions of Delphi has `System.Hash`, but older version such as Delphi 7 does not.

Which version of Delphi introduced the `System.Hash` unit?

Comment: While as per **Help > About** Delphi 7 is [from 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Delphi_(software)#Borland_Delphi_7), so the vast majority of Delphi versions is "_newer_". Thumb of rule: if the unit name has no dots (unit scope names), it's [from 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Delphi_(software)#Embarcadero_Delphi_XE2[9]) or before.

Comment: you mean "outdated version such as Delphi 7"!

Comment: @DelphiCoder: I think the OP means *Delphi versions that are within a year or two of being a quarter-decade old*. Isn't 25 years when something is considered as being antique?

Comment: @KenWhite That would also mean [NTFS 3.1 (used nowadays)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Versions) is _antique_.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Yes, and Windows 95 (still used today for some reason). I guess people who can't upgrade (compatibility with old apps, budget, ???) have their reasons, but I'd find a way around those reasons somehow.

Comment: @KenWhite You cannot upgrade NTFS 3.1 - it's still the most recent version and also used with Win11. Consider clicking my link.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Of course. I read that as NT 3.1, not NTFS. :-) Yet another note to self about posting before the coffee kicks in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `System.Hash` unit was introduced in Delphi XE8 in 2015.